# How to create a column where all values from A are linked to B?

Tags: microsoft-excel, script

I even had a problem to formulate the question. I will give you an example and then I think it will be more understandable. Let's say we have the following data in Excel:

[image: Data table]

And then I want to connect every single value from the column 'Name' with the column 'City', having this at the end:

[image: Result]

How is this possible to get with Excel?

I know it's very simple to make with a script if you are a programmer, but I'm not and I need a solution for this.

Basically I am looking for the equivalent of a 'Cross Join' in Excel

Comment: Google how to use VLOOKUP, its like the first thing to learn, and one of the most used functions in Excel

Comment: @PeterH I don't think Tony wants a VLOOKUP here. I think the first example is what he has, and the 2nd is what he wants it to become. A VLOOKUP will not work in that case.

Comment: @LPChip yep youre right

Comment: Hi Tony, welcome to SuperUser. The solution you're looking for will requite VBA (or a macro) Unfortunately, we're not a "Please write me a script kind of service." You can manually record actions to get VBA code and construct something like that. If you provide a script, we can help you debug why the script is not working correctly. Alternatively, consider doing it manually.

Comment: https://www.contextures.com/excelmsquerycartesian.html

Comment: It honestly depends on how long your list of names is. If you have a fairly small number of names, say, 10-15 tops, you could just copy and paste the repeating block of cities and then add in the names.. This approach is certainly not a good choice if your list is significantly larger, but if you only have a few names, it may be easier than trying to follow the logic of a complex formula.

Comment: LPChip Thanks for the comment. I know you this is not a "write me a script" and I don't want that. I'd like to be self-sufficient. The thing is I encounter this problem last week at work but with 500 records for column A and 100 for column B, so doing that manually would be very time consuming. My workmate knows some programming and wrote a simple script. In 10 minutes it was done, but I don't want to depend on him every time so I was hoping to find a formula to do it with Excel.

I am aware of VLOOKUP but that will not help me in this situation.

Comment: @Tony, you can use a lookup of some form to fill in blanks, but the information needs to exist somewhere.  In your example, you have names with no assigned city.  There is nothing in Excel that will allow it to divine such information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your NAME column starts in A1, and the City column starts in B1, you can use the below:

In C2 use:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROUND((ROW())/4,0)+1)
```

And in D2 use:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,IF(RIGHT(ROW()/4,2)=".5",1,IF(RIGHT(ROW()/4,3)=".75",2,IF(RIGHT(ROW()/4,3)=".25",4,3)))+1,1)
```

Then drag them both down for as far required.